# How do I fix "The query parameter [expansion] is not one of [usernames,expansions,tweet.fields,user.fields]" in twitter R Script

Tags: r, api, twitter

I am running the following code which is taken from https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-r-and-v2-of-the-twitter-ap with some slight changes because it is doesn't seem to work.

```
library(rjson)
#https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/getting-started-with-r-and-v2-of-the-twitter-ap
Sys.setenv(BEARER_TOKEN="{mybearertoken}")
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
require(dplyr)
bearer_token <- Sys.getenv("TWITTER_BEARER")
headers <- c(`Authorization` = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))
params <- list(`user.fields` = 'description',
               `expansion` = 'pinned_tweet_id')
handle <- "codewryte"
url_handle <- paste("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/", handle)

#url_handle <-"https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/1228393702244134912"
response <-
  httr::GET(url = url_handle,
            httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
            query = params)
obj <- httr::content(response, as = "text")
x <- fromJSON(obj)
```

I get the following error:

```
$errors[[2]]$message
[1] "The query parameter [expansion] is not one of [usernames,expansions,tweet.fields,user.fields]"



$title
[1] "Invalid Request"

$detail
[1] "One or more parameters to your request was invalid."

$type
[1] "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"
```

I also tried https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/codewryte which is my user handle with the same message.

Does anyone understand what this message means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was sending a list where a string needed to be sent.

```
response <-httr::GET(url = url_handle,
            httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
            query="expansions=pinned_tweet_id&user.fields=created_at&tweet.fields=created_at")
```

I am not sure why the tutorial had this list.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. A lot of tutorials seem to be... almost right

Comment: This gives me 400 error.